# suspect database due to in-memory tables and resource governor(?)

Tags: crash, in-memory-database, sql-server-2019, alwayson, resource-governor

Last night, both nodes on our Alwayson AG cluster went down at the same time. After a restart, only databases containing in-memory tables were marked as suspect. In the errorlog I see this message: (fragment)

```
2022-02-03 02:20:12.480 Resource governor reconfiguration succeeded. 
2022-02-03 02:21:11.570 Resource pool 'inMemory' does not exist or resource governor has not been reconfigured. 
2022-02-03 02:21:12.720 Database 'XXXXX' cannot be opened. It has been marked SUSPECT by recovery. See the SQL Server errorlog for more information.
```

I checked:

- resource governor was up and running
- resourcepool 'inMemory' defined

Any idea why only this combination (AOAG/XTP/RG) leads to a suspect database? Other databases had not this issue (and several processes were running on other databases at time of the crash)
environment: SQL2019 CU14, 2node AlwaysOn synchronous, Windows Server 2019